# smartsheet seems to be reusing session

Tags: python, selenium

so in my python code first i am going into another website and downloading a file using selenium,
quit the selenium by doing driver.quit() and then as next step i am downloading a file from Smartsheet ,

it seems like smartsheet is reusing the session i established earlier in selenium

the code runs fine independently

```
import smartsheet
import json

access_token=''
download_directory_path='c:\\Incoming\\'
# Initialize client
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
contents = json.loads(str(smartsheet_client.Home.list_all_contents(include='source')))

smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(1829801544705924,download_directory_path)
# Make sure we don't miss any errors
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)
```

stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023D8D213D68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloadfile.py", line 108, in <module>
    Downloadfile()
  File "downloadfile.py", line 77, in DownloadAggdata
    cell_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FinalXPath).text
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 79, in request
    method, url, fields=fields, headers=headers, **urlopen_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 796, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 796, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 796, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=56988): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/5b42bcd2457bb5dce275ba3720168b1e/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023D8D213D68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

Comment: "/session/5b42bcd2457bb5dce275ba3720168b1e/element" is a Selenium webdriver call to the browser.  (Wire protocol...)  The exception there suggests that a call is being made to a browser that is no longer open.   Fix that part and see if it helps... File "downloadfile.py", line 77

Comment: thanks.. that was it ..